# Data not deleting from database

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm trying to delete a row from my database, but it doesn't seem to be deleting.  Any suggestions why the database isn't updating?  Code is below:

```
<form method="get">

<table>
    <tr><td>Email Address </td>
    <td><input name="e" type="text" size="25"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input name="delete" type="submit" value="Remove"/>

</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
        $query = oci_parse($conn,'DELETE FROM tbl WHERE email = :e');
        oci_bind_by_name($query, ':e', $_GET['e']);
        oci_execute($query);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check the affected row count, and try to `trim()` the GET variable.

Comment: have you checked to see if its returning an error?

Comment: I don't see a `commit` in the code.

Comment: There's no errors in the error console in the web browser.  I've printed the query, and it's showing $query = "Resource id #4"  Not sure why that is?  I've added oci_close($conn) at the end, but I believe oracle doesn't require a commit.  Is that right?

Comment: Also added action = "page.php" in the form tag.  I'm not sure if that makes any difference or not though.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
'DELETE FROM tbl WHERE email = :e'
```

to

```
'DELETE FROM tbl WHERE email = ":e"'
```

Comment: I don't know how the binding functions go over that string, but it might be a better idea to have `"DELETE FROM tbl WHERE email = ':e'"` because imo double quote are reserved for identifiers.

Comment: Even if `:e` get's replaced, this will cause an error because e.g. `"foo@bar.com"` would  a **column reference** not a String value. As mistapink pointed out, double quotes are for identifiers, single quotes are for string literals in standard SQL (and Oracle complies with the standard)

Comment: @Sandra:; it can't possibly work with double quotes. It's a totally wrong answer and I don't understand why it has been upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, there's no need for surrounding the binding variables with quotes: [docs](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

What might be happening: the string you are trying to match is a little bit different from what is in the database. Something like "example@example.com" versus "EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM", a leading space. The way you implemented the deletion, both strings would have to be **exactly** equal for the deletion to take place.

I suggest you try something like this:
`DELETE FROM tbl WHERE trim(upper(email)) = tirm(upper(:e))`

or, make sure all the email columns on your table are stored properly and use the function only on the binding variable part:
`DELETE FROM tbl WHERE email = trim(upper(:e))`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned:

```
<form method="get">

<table>
    <tr><td>Email Address </td>
    <td><input name="e" type="text" size="25"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input name="delete" type="submit" value="Remove"/>

</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
        $query = oci_parse($conn,"DELETE FROM tbl WHERE upper(email) = trim(upper(':e'))");
        oci_bind_by_name($query, ':e', $_GET['e']);
        oci_execute($query);
    }
?>
```